# why does this simple Keras model have two parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I try to understand how models and layers in Keras work. I created very simple model which has - or at least it was my intention that it has - one input, one output and one connection between them:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', input_shape=(1,)))
```

I expected that it will have one parameter - a number by which input is multiplicated to produce output - but when I display the model's summary, I see that it has *two* parameters:

```
model.summary()

Model: "sequential_7"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 2         
=================================================================
Total params: 2
Trainable params: 2
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Also, when I print the weights, I see two of them:

```
model.get_weights()
[array([[0.02002084]], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32)]
```

Why does this model have two parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The other parameter is a bias, which is added to the multiplication result. I can prove it this way:

```
import numpy as np
weights = [np.asarray([[44]]), np.asarray([10])]
model.set_weights(wagi)
model.predict([1])

array([[54.]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Formula to get number of parameters:

output_size * (input_size+1) == number of parameters.

In your case, output_size and input_size are 1
So , number of parameter is 2.